# RenderPass Dependency and (transition) memory barrier

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am facing a comprehensive issue.

Let's say I have an image in a TRANSFER_LAYOUT layout. Going that way, the memory is already made available (not visible).

Let's say I update a uniform buffer (via vkCmdCopyBuffer).

Now let's say I have a renderPass (with an "empty frameBuffer", so there is no colorAttachment to make thing simpler) that use the prior image in SHADER_READ_OPTIMAL layout and the uniform buffer we just update. The image and the buffer are both used inside the fragment shader.

Is it correct to do the following?

Transition the image to SHADER_READ_LAYOUT

```
srcAccess = 0; // layers will say error : it must be TRANSFER_READ
dstAccess = 0; // The visibility will be made in the renderpass dependency (hower layers tells that it should be SHADER_READ I think)
srcPipe = TOP_OF_PIPE;
dstPipe = BOTTOM_OF_PIPE;
```

It is, in my understanding, meaningless to use different access than 0 here because `TOP_OF_PIPE` and `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` does not access memory.

In the renderpass dependency from VK_EXTERNAL_SUBPASS :

```
srcAccess = TRANSFER_WRITE; // for the uniformBuffer
dstAccess = SHADER_READ; // for the uniform and the image
srcPipeline = TRANSFER; // For the uniformBuffer
dstPipeline = FRAGMENT_SHADER; // They are used here
```

Going that way, we are sure that the uniform buffer will not have any problems : The data are both made available and visible thanks to the renderPass. The memory should also be made visible for the image (also thanks to the dependency). However, the transition is write here to happened "not before" the bottom stage. Since I am using the image in FRAGMENT_STAGE, is it a mistake? Or is the "end of the renderPass dependency" behave like a bottom stage?

This code works on NVIDIA, and on AMD, but I am not sure it is really correct

Comment: I am getting little bit lost in it. To my understanding your question is about synchronization of an image; how exactly is the buffer in your question relevant to anything?

Comment: It is not only for the image. I may remove the buffer here, but the answer will be something like : Make a dependency top to bottom without any access and a barrier for your image just before the renderPass and it will be good. And that is something I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: Seems valid-ish to me. Except the `srcPipe=TOP_OF_PIPE, dstPipe=BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. Do you by any chance have `src` and `dst` swapped? Or do you have some other stuff to enforce _execution dependency_ you did not mention (semaphors, other barriers chained to these)?

Comment: No just the renderpass dépendency. That is why I wanted to know if it is good or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand synchronization perfectly, one must simply read the specification; especially the [Execution and Memory Dependencies](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies) theory chapter. Lets analyze your situation in terms of what is written in the specification.

You have (only) three synchronization commands: **S<sub>1</sub>** (image transition to `TRANSFER_LAYOUT` and availability operation), **S<sub>2</sub>** (image transition to `SHADER_READ_LAYOUT`), and **S<sub>3</sub>** (render pass `VK_EXTERNAL` dependency).

Your command buffer is an ordered list like: [**Cmds<sub>0</sub>**, **S<sub>1</sub>**, **Cmds<sub>1</sub>**, **S<sub>2</sub>**, **Cmds<sub>2</sub>**, **S<sub>3</sub>**, **Cmds<sub>3</sub>**].

For **S<sub>1</sub>** let's assume you did the first part of a dependency (i.e. `src` part) correctly. You only said you made the image *available from*.

You also said you did **not** made it *visible to*, so let's assume `dstAccess` was `0` and `dstStage` was probably `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`.

**S<sub>2</sub>** has no *execution dependency* and it has not *memory dependency*. Only layout transition. There is an [layout transition synchronization](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-image-barrier-layout-transition-order) exception in the spec saying that layout transitions are performed in full in *submission order* (i.e. *implicit execution dependency* is automagically added). I personally would not be comfortable relying on it (and I would not trust drivers to implement it correctly on the first try). But lets assume it is valid, and assume the image will be correctly transitioned and made *available from* (and not *visible to*) at some point after the **S<sub>1</sub>**.

The **S<sub>3</sub>** is an external subpass dependency on non-attachment resource, but [the spec reassures us](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkSubpassDependency) it is no different than `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` with a `VkMemoryBarrier`.

The second part of the dependency (i.e. `dst`) in **S<sub>3</sub>** seems correct for your needs.

---

TL;DR, so far so good.

---

The first part of the dependency (i.e. `dst`) in **S<sub>3</sub>** would indeed be the problematic one.

There is no automatic layout transitions for non-attachment resources, so we cannot rely on that crutch as above.

Set of commands **A<sub>3</sub>** are all the commands before the renderpass.

Synchronization scope **A<sub>3S</sub>** are only those kinds of *operations* that are on the `srcStage` pipline stage or any logically earlier stage (i.e. `TOP_OF_PIPE` up to the specified `STAGE_TRANSFER`).

The *execution dependency* is made between **A<sub>3</sub>'** and **B<sub>3</sub>'**. Above we agreed the **B<sub>3</sub>'** half of the dependency is correct. The **A<sub>3</sub>'** half is intersection of **A<sub>3</sub>** and **A<sub>3S</sub>**.

The layout transition in **S<sub>2</sub>** is made between `srcPipe = TOP_OF_PIPE` and `dstPipe = BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`, so basically can be anywhere. It can be as late as in `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` (to be precise, happens-before `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` of commands recorded after **S<sub>2</sub>** is executed).
So the layout transition is part of **A<sub>3</sub>**, but there is no guarantee it is part of **A<sub>3S</sub>**; so there would **not** be guarantee the transition is part of the intersection **A<sub>3</sub>'**.

That means there is no guarantee the layout transition to `SHADER_READ_LAYOUT` happens-before the image reading in the first subpass in `STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER`.

There is no correct *memory dependency* either because that is defined in terms of **A<sub>3</sub>'** too.

EDIT: Somehow missed this, which is probably the problem:

> Or is the "end of the renderPass dependency" behave like a bottom stage?

Beginning and end of a render pass does not behave like anything. It only affects *submission order*. In the presence of `VK_EXTERNAL` dependency only that applies (and of course any other previous explicit synchronization commands). What happens without explicit `VK_EXTERNAL` dependency is described in the spec too bellow Valid Usage sections of [VkSubpassDependency](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkSubpassDependency) (basically all memory that is *available*  before `TOP_OF_PIPE` is made *visible to* the whole first subpass for attachment use).

Comment: I guess it answers the question. However I disagree with "It can be as late as in BOTTOM_OF_PIPE (to be precise, happens-before BOTTOM_OF_PIPE of commands recorded after S2 is executed)." Because you said that there is an "implicit" execution dependency for layout transition. If there is no implicit execution dependency, I agree you are right, but here I disagree. or maybe I did not understand well what your meant

Comment: @AntoineMorrier There is implicit execution dependency **between** layout transitions. There's no layout transition in the render pass and so there cannot be implicit dependency between the **S2** transition and the use in the subpass.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Of course synchronization in Vulkan is tricky and so my answer could use second set of eyes to fact check.

Comment: Okay so It was a good idea to ask this question ^^. I am happy to had put the correct answer in my engine :). Thank you ;)